# Dragging a google maps placemark over non-land

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In a website Im working on, I need the user to locate his/her property over a map. I do that by making use of draggable placemarks in google maps v3.

How could I limit the user to drag a placemark over a land only, no sea.

Thanks

Comment: You mean I can't select my property I bought over the sea?! Not fair! **>:(**

Answer (score 0):

That information isn't available in the Google Maps API v3.  If you know the region of interest, you can create polygons containing either the allowed regions or the disallowed regions and write code to prevent that.  Probably would be most user friendly to wait until the drag end event, then move the marker out of the disallowed region or let the user know that they need to move it.

Comment: User is allowed to select any region. For instance according to you, when user selects a country, I can draw a polygon over that country, but can I force user to drag only to a polygon? Thanks